# Medium.com Menu Horizontal Style - See Pic Example

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I am trying to make my menu system look exactly like how medium has it however I just seem to not be able to get the Arrows to show up on left and right of the menu itself. As provided in the example image or you can view it here

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  /*   background-color: #333; */
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
} */
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#support">Support</a>
  <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  <a href="#base">Base</a>
  <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
  <a href="#more">More</a>
  <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
  <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
  <a href="#people">People</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
</div>
```

An answer to the arrows is what Im hunting and would be appreciated.
[image: Image Example]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I worked on my own answer. Thanks anyways, my answer is below and I hope this will answer someone's question in the future:

```js
var SETTINGS = {
  navBarTravelling: false,
  navBarTravelDirection: "",
  navBarTravelDistance: 150
}

var colours = {
  0: "#867100",
  1: "#7F4200",
  2: "#99813D",
  3: "#40FEFF",
  4: "#14CC99",
  5: "#00BAFF",
  6: "#0082B2",
  7: "#B25D7A",
  8: "#00FF17",
  9: "#006B49",
  10: "#00B27A",
  11: "#996B3D",
  12: "#CC7014",
  13: "#40FF8C",
  14: "#FF3400",
  15: "#ECBB5E",
  16: "#ECBB0C",
  17: "#B9D912",
  18: "#253A93",
  19: "#125FB9",
}

document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

// Out advancer buttons
var pnAdvancerLeft = document.getElementById("pnAdvancerLeft");
var pnAdvancerRight = document.getElementById("pnAdvancerRight");
// the indicator
var pnIndicator = document.getElementById("pnIndicator");

var pnProductNav = document.getElementById("pnProductNav");
var pnProductNavContents = document.getElementById("pnProductNavContents");

pnProductNav.setAttribute("data-overflowing", determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav));

// Set the indicator
moveIndicator(pnProductNav.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours[0]);

// Handle the scroll of the horizontal container
var last_known_scroll_position = 0;
var ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
  pnProductNav.setAttribute("data-overflowing", determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav));
}

pnProductNav.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;
  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });
  }
  ticking = true;
});


pnAdvancerLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // If in the middle of a move return
  if (SETTINGS.navBarTravelling === true) {
    return;
  }
  // If we have content overflowing both sides or on the left
  if (determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav) === "left" || determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav) === "both") {
    // Find how far this panel has been scrolled
    var availableScrollLeft = pnProductNav.scrollLeft;
    // If the space available is less than two lots of our desired distance, just move the whole amount
    // otherwise, move by the amount in the settings
    if (availableScrollLeft < SETTINGS.navBarTravelDistance * 2) {
      pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "translateX(" + availableScrollLeft + "px)";
    } else {
      pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "translateX(" + SETTINGS.navBarTravelDistance + "px)";
    }
    // We do want a transition (this is set in CSS) when moving so remove the class that would prevent that
    pnProductNavContents.classList.remove("pn-ProductNav_Contents-no-transition");
    // Update our settings
    SETTINGS.navBarTravelDirection = "left";
    SETTINGS.navBarTravelling = true;
  }
  // Now update the attribute in the DOM
  pnProductNav.setAttribute("data-overflowing", determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav));
});

pnAdvancerRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // If in the middle of a move return
  if (SETTINGS.navBarTravelling === true) {
    return;
  }
  // If we have content overflowing both sides or on the right
  if (determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav) === "right" || determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav) === "both") {
    // Get the right edge of the container and content
    var navBarRightEdge = pnProductNavContents.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    var navBarScrollerRightEdge = pnProductNav.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    // Now we know how much space we have available to scroll
    var availableScrollRight = Math.floor(navBarRightEdge - navBarScrollerRightEdge);
    // If the space available is less than two lots of our desired distance, just move the whole amount
    // otherwise, move by the amount in the settings
    if (availableScrollRight < SETTINGS.navBarTravelDistance * 2) {
      pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "translateX(-" + availableScrollRight + "px)";
    } else {
      pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "translateX(-" + SETTINGS.navBarTravelDistance + "px)";
    }
    // We do want a transition (this is set in CSS) when moving so remove the class that would prevent that
    pnProductNavContents.classList.remove("pn-ProductNav_Contents-no-transition");
    // Update our settings
    SETTINGS.navBarTravelDirection = "right";
    SETTINGS.navBarTravelling = true;
  }
  // Now update the attribute in the DOM
  pnProductNav.setAttribute("data-overflowing", determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav));
});

pnProductNavContents.addEventListener(
  "transitionend",
  function() {
    // get the value of the transform, apply that to the current scroll position (so get the scroll pos first) and then remove the transform
    var styleOfTransform = window.getComputedStyle(pnProductNavContents, null);
    var tr = styleOfTransform.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") || styleOfTransform.getPropertyValue("transform");
    // If there is no transition we want to default to 0 and not null
    var amount = Math.abs(parseInt(tr.split(",")[4]) || 0);
    pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "none";
    pnProductNavContents.classList.add("pn-ProductNav_Contents-no-transition");
    // Now lets set the scroll position
    if (SETTINGS.navBarTravelDirection === "left") {
      pnProductNav.scrollLeft = pnProductNav.scrollLeft - amount;
    } else {
      pnProductNav.scrollLeft = pnProductNav.scrollLeft + amount;
    }
    SETTINGS.navBarTravelling = false;
  },
  false
);

// Handle setting the currently active link
pnProductNavContents.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".pn-ProductNav_Link"));
  links.forEach(function(item) {
    item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
  })
  e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
  // Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
  moveIndicator(e.target, colours[links.indexOf(e.target)]);
});

// var count = 0;
function moveIndicator(item, color) {
  var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
  var container = pnProductNavContents.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var distance = textPosition.left - container;
  var scroll = pnProductNavContents.scrollLeft;
  pnIndicator.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
  // count = count += 100;
  // pnIndicator.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";

  if (color) {
    pnIndicator.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}

function determineOverflow(content, container) {
  var containerMetrics = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  var containerMetricsRight = Math.floor(containerMetrics.right);
  var containerMetricsLeft = Math.floor(containerMetrics.left);
  var contentMetrics = content.getBoundingClientRect();
  var contentMetricsRight = Math.floor(contentMetrics.right);
  var contentMetricsLeft = Math.floor(contentMetrics.left);
  if (containerMetricsLeft > contentMetricsLeft && containerMetricsRight < contentMetricsRight) {
    return "both";
  } else if (contentMetricsLeft < containerMetricsLeft) {
    return "left";
  } else if (contentMetricsRight > containerMetricsRight) {
    return "right";
  } else {
    return "none";
  }
}

/**
 * @fileoverview dragscroll - scroll area by dragging
 * @version 0.0.8
 * 
 * @license MIT, see https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll
 * @copyright 2015 asvd <heliosframework@gmail.com> 
 */


(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['exports'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    factory(exports);
  } else {
    factory((root.dragscroll = {}));
  }
}(this, function(exports) {
  var _window = window;
  var _document = document;
  var mousemove = 'mousemove';
  var mouseup = 'mouseup';
  var mousedown = 'mousedown';
  var EventListener = 'EventListener';
  var addEventListener = 'add' + EventListener;
  var removeEventListener = 'remove' + EventListener;
  var newScrollX, newScrollY;

  var dragged = [];
  var reset = function(i, el) {
    for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
      el = dragged[i++];
      el = el.container || el;
      el[removeEventListener](mousedown, el.md, 0);
      _window[removeEventListener](mouseup, el.mu, 0);
      _window[removeEventListener](mousemove, el.mm, 0);
    }

    // cloning into array since HTMLCollection is updated dynamically
    dragged = [].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName('dragscroll'));
    for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
      (function(el, lastClientX, lastClientY, pushed, scroller, cont) {
        (cont = el.container || el)[addEventListener](
          mousedown,
          cont.md = function(e) {
            if (!el.hasAttribute('nochilddrag') ||
              _document.elementFromPoint(
                e.pageX, e.pageY
              ) == cont
            ) {
              pushed = 1;
              lastClientX = e.clientX;
              lastClientY = e.clientY;

              e.preventDefault();
            }
          }, 0
        );

        _window[addEventListener](
          mouseup, cont.mu = function() {
            pushed = 0;
          }, 0
        );

        _window[addEventListener](
          mousemove,
          cont.mm = function(e) {
            if (pushed) {
              (scroller = el.scroller || el).scrollLeft -=
                newScrollX = (-lastClientX + (lastClientX = e.clientX));
              scroller.scrollTop -=
                newScrollY = (-lastClientY + (lastClientY = e.clientY));
              if (el == _document.body) {
                (scroller = _document.documentElement).scrollLeft -= newScrollX;
                scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY;
              }
            }
          }, 0
        );
      })(dragged[i++]);
    }
  }


  if (_document.readyState == 'complete') {
    reset();
  } else {
    _window[addEventListener]('load', reset, 0);
  }

  exports.reset = reset;
}));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 11px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pn-ProductNav {
  /* Make this scrollable when needed */
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
  /* positioning context for advancers */
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
}

.js .pn-ProductNav {
  /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
}

.js .pn-ProductNav::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Contents {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Contents-no-transition {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 44px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0 11px;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Link+.pn-ProductNav_Link {
  border-left-color: #eee;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Link[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
}

.pn-Advancer {
  /* Reset the button */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  /* Now style it as needed */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Set the buttons invisible by default */
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.pn-Advancer:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.pn-Advancer:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pn-Advancer_Left {
  left: 0;
}

[data-overflowing="both"]~.pn-Advancer_Left,
[data-overflowing="left"]~.pn-Advancer_Left {
  opacity: 1;
}

.pn-Advancer_Right {
  right: 0;
}

[data-overflowing="both"]~.pn-Advancer_Right,
[data-overflowing="right"]~.pn-Advancer_Right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.pn-Advancer_Icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 44px;
  fill: #bbb;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="pn-ProductNav_Wrapper">
  <nav id="pnProductNav" class="pn-ProductNav">
    <div id="pnProductNavContents" class="pn-ProductNav_Contents">
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link" aria-selected="true">Chairs</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Tables</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Cookware</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Beds</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Desks</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Flooring</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Lighting</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Mattresses</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Solar Panels</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Bookcases</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Mirrors</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Rugs</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Curtains &amp; Blinds</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Frames &amp; Pictures</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Wardrobes</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Storage</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Decoration</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Appliances</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Racks</a>
      <a href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Worktops</a>
      <span id="pnIndicator" class="pn-ProductNav_Indicator"></span>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <button id="pnAdvancerLeft" class="pn-Advancer pn-Advancer_Left" type="button">
        <svg class="pn-Advancer_Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 551 1024"><path d="M445.44 38.183L-2.53 512l447.97 473.817 85.857-81.173-409.6-433.23v81.172l409.6-433.23L445.44 38.18z"/></svg>
    </button>
  <button id="pnAdvancerRight" class="pn-Advancer pn-Advancer_Right" type="button">
        <svg class="pn-Advancer_Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 551 1024"><path d="M105.56 985.817L553.53 512 105.56 38.183l-85.857 81.173 409.6 433.23v-81.172l-409.6 433.23 85.856 81.174z"/></svg>
    </button>
</div>

You can also view my demo on codepen where I worked it up at.
<p /> https://codepen.io/REthinkify/pen/KKVezJL
```